# visual studio installer has stopped working 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I have window 7 operating system i need to install Visual Studio on my computer but when i start the visual studio installer it say "Visual Studio installer has stopped working." and it finally stop. any one can help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Please provide screenshots of the error.

Comment: visual studio installer has stopped working. 
Windows is checking for a solution to the problem.... and suddenly stopped!! I cant post screenshots image in StackoverFlow.com i think!!

Comment: You can post pictures in stackoverflow posts just edit your Question and click on six icon from the left which has picture like icon and then you would be able to add screenshot.

Comment: Sir we can't understand what is the issue you are facing. Tell what version of Visual studio are you trying to install. You can see official tutorial for how to install Visual Studio by opening this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/install-visual-studio